# Query all page titles in a wiki?

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-api

Im querying a wiki that has urls structured like:

`wiki.xxxxxxx.com/index.php?title=titleofarticlehere`

How could I get a list of all pages (the "titleofarticlehere" part above^)?

Comment: what do you want to do? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Get a list of page titles in the wiki...just like the post says. What should I try?

Comment: literally: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Allpages

Answer (score 2):

For what usages do you want it? There is a special page "Special:AllPages" to view all pages in this wiki, or you could use [a machine readable list using the api](https://de.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Ballpages).

Comment: Ok cool, getting there. So i have a basic query working: `/api.php?action=query&list=allpages&format=jsonfm` but this seems to only bring back 10 results, with an "apcontinue" option at the top. Adding `apcontinue=` + whatever string it gives me brings back the next 10 results. How can I query for ALL results at once? Also, how would you query for all pages within certain categories?

Comment: Have you read the api doc? :) With aplimit you can set the maximum pages for that query (up to 500 for logged in users and 5000 for bots). Returning _all_ (so, REALLY all) pages doesn't make any sense and isn't supported, it would take to much resources at once :)